# Multiple joins with order by and group by not returning what I expect

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that I am trying to implement and there is something not quite right.

Here are the basics of the tables (I left out unnecessary things and also the indexes and foreign key stuff):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PROJECT` (
      `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `USER_ID` INT NULL ,
      `NAME` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
      `PROJECT_NUMBER` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
      `CREATION_DATE` DATETIME NULL 


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MODEL` (
      `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `PROJECT_ID` INT NOT NULL ,

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SIMULATION_SET` (
      `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `MODEL_ID` INT NULL ,
      `CREATION_DATE` DATETIME NULL ,
      `START_TIME` DATETIME NULL ,
      `END_TIME` DATETIME NULL
```

What I am trying to do is this:  I want to get the projects that have the most recent simulations sets for a particular user.  This is an example of query:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.USER_ID, P.NAME, P.PROJECT_NUMBER, S.ID SET_ID, S.START_TIME
 FROM PROJECT P 
   INNER JOIN MODEL M ON M.PROJECT_ID=P.ID 
   INNER JOIN SIMULATION_SET S ON S.MODEL_ID=M.ID 
   WHERE P.USER_ID=5 AND S.START_TIME IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY P.ID 
   ORDER BY S.START_TIME DESC LIMIT 5
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, and the problem is the group by seems to filter it such that I am getting the first simulation_set in the table for each project, whereas what I want it to be sorted by is the last.  Without the GROUP BY, I get the list of all the simulation sets for the user, ordered correctly.  What I want is the projects in that order, but I don't get it.

On a sample set, without the group by, I get this, which is ordered correctly:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | name            | project_number | SET_ID | start_time          |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
| 14 |       5 | Krusty Krab     | 123            |    267 | 2011-07-07 14:57:15 |
| 16 |       5 | Pineapple       | p456           |    266 | 2011-07-07 12:48:58 |
| 21 |       5 | Patrick's House | US             |    265 | 2011-07-07 12:48:18 |
| 14 |       5 | Krusty Krab     | 123            |    264 | 2011-07-07 12:47:42 |
| 13 |       5 | Bikini Bottom   | B123           |    263 | 2011-07-07 12:44:07 |
| 16 |       5 | Pineapple       | p456           |    262 | 2011-07-07 12:42:52 |
| 14 |       5 | Krusty Krab     | 123            |    261 | 2011-07-07 12:41:52 |
| 16 |       5 | Pineapple       | p456           |    260 | 2011-07-07 12:40:21 |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
```

With the GROUP BY clause, I get this:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | name            | project_number | SET_ID | start_time          |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
| 21 |       5 | Patrick's House | US             |    265 | 2011-07-07 12:48:18 |
| 13 |       5 | Bikini Bottom   | B123           |    263 | 2011-07-07 12:44:07 |
| 14 |       5 | Krusty Krab     | 123            |    261 | 2011-07-07 12:41:52 |
| 16 |       5 | Pineapple       | p456           |    260 | 2011-07-07 12:40:21 |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------------------+
```

The order is wrong, and it pulls the start_time from the earliest, whereas I want it ordered from the latest.  The first Project in the list should be Krusty Krab.  I was thinking I might need to do subqueries to do this, but I am not sure how.   I know that SQL wizards will find this obvious, or at least I hope so!  Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: helpful article : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: The only time you should ever use `GROUP BY` is if you're using an aggregate function (like `SUM` or `COUNT`), which you're not doing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "What I want is the projects in that order, but I don't get it." You are getting the projects in that order, they're just not distinct.

Comment: user349433 I guess what I want is distinct.  Thanks for that info about group by, that makes sense

Comment: diEcho- thanks for that article, reading it now and going to give it a try.  I had a feeling I needed to use a subquery, but not sure how.

Comment: Ok, I've tried a few things and i still can't seem to get what I want.  Simply, I just want a lit of the N projects with the most recent simulation sets.  It seems like it should be easy, and I know I should be able to figure it out! I  think what's confusing me is the join to get from simulation_set to model, then to project.  Any specific thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which db you use, but in your request it seems really strange to me to group by the id, and to not aggregate the other results...

Even if the id is the primary key, that seems not allowed on the Oracle we have at work...

Anyway you are grouping by project id, ok, but the result you are supposed to get can be linked to multiple simulation sets.

Considering that when you group by project you only show one line for each project, how the db is supposed to know what to put in that line since it has multiple simulation values? This is why you must aggregate the results that are not part of the group by... But in your case this wouldn't work very well because the multiple aggretates are not linked together. Using a MAX on start time will show you the max start time for each project, but you won't be able to retrieve the correct name related to that max start time of a given project.

I don't see anything else except using subselect like others already said

Comment: Maybe I am using the group by wrong, because I tried that to get one row per project.  Basically what I want is the projects in the order of last simulation run, and when I didn't use the group by, I got multiple ones.  I also thought I need to use the sub-select, but I didn't know how

Comment: although your answer is a little ambiguous, I followed some of what you said and I think it's working.  What I ended up doing that worked was doing ORDER BY MAX(START_TIME) DESC.   I only showed the set_id and name on this query for display, what I really only need is the model.  So using that info that would the group by, I also needed to use MAX on something to aggregate, it seems to be working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was too fast to answer the first time, it wasn't clear and it was also a bit wrong...
Here's an SQL that should do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.USER_ID, P.NAME, P.PROJECT_NUMBER, S.ID SET_ID, S.START_TIME
FROM PROJECT P
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT P.ID, MAX(S.START_TIME) as MAX_TIME
      FROM PROJECT P 
           INNER JOIN MODEL M ON M.PROJECT_ID=P.ID 
           INNER JOIN SIMULATION_SET S ON S.MODEL_ID=M.ID 
           WHERE P.USER_ID=5 AND S.START_TIME IS NOT NULL 
      GROUP BY P.ID) PMAX ON P.ID = PMAX.ID

     INNER JOIN MODEL M ON M.PROJECT_ID=P.ID 
     INNER JOIN SIMULATION_SET S ON S.MODEL_ID=M.ID 
                                 AND S.START_TIME = PMAX.MAX_TIME

ORDER BY S.START_TIME DESC LIMIT 5
```

A couple of notes:
The only purpose of the inner SELECT is to get the maximum start time for every project.
The outer select than performs the necessary joins again to find the set ID. 
(If you don't need the `SET_ID` in the select, you can remove the outer joins for `MODEL` and `SIMULATION_SET`)

There is no way (that I can think of) to get the `SET_ID` out of the inner join, since you are aggregating by project id which can contain several sets.

Another thing to note is you do not need a `WHERE` clause on the outer select because the projects will already be filtered to contain only projects with `USER_ID = 5`.

I hope that makes more sense...

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I want, but getting close?  The Limit needs to be number of projects, and the last many simulation sets could be a single project.  I only used the group by to get distinct.  When I tried to use the distinct keyword, it still didn't order correctly, because what I want is distinct project.

Comment: Do you have any specific thoughts on the ... you have?  I'm trying to figure out what to use for them and I'm coming up empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, my first answer was too short and confusing. I edited the answer above to make it clearer. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I actually don't need the set_id which is good, since that does complicate things.  I did get it working the other day, which is good!